# Problem on product topology and products of sets

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I was thinking of proving it in 2 parts: Firstly showing that LHS is a subset of RHS and then RHS is a subset of LHS. If those 2 holds, then we can say that LHS = RHS. But, when I started doing the 1st one, I completely got messed up with bar of (A X B) and its complement. Is bar of that thing a complement or closure?

Also, can I use De-Morgans law to show this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thnx in advance.

Comment: The bar is closure.

Comment: Ok, then i need to show that the product of the closure of 2 sets (i..e A X B) is equal to the closure of A X closure of B, right?

Answer (score 1):

The bar is the standard notation for [the closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)). I will use the following two properties of closures: let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ a subset. Then:

1. If $C$ is a closed subset such that $A\subseteq C$, then $\overline{A}\subseteq C$.
2. $x\in\overline{A}$ if and only if for any open subset $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$ we have $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

---

So let's prove that $\overline{A\times B}=\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ by showing two inclusions:

"$\subseteq$" Since $A\times B\subseteq \overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ and the set on the right is closed, then $\overline{A\times B}\subseteq \overline{A}\times\overline{B}$. $\Box$

For "$\supseteq$" consider $(x,y)\in\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ and consider an open neighbourhood $W$ of $(x,y)$ in $X\times Y$. It is enough to show that $W\cap(A\times B)\neq\emptyset$.

Indeed, by the definition of product topology this means that $(x,y)\in U\times V\subseteq W$ for some open subsets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$. Since $x$ belongs to the closure of $A$ then $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$. Analogously $y$ belongs to the closure of $B$ and so $B\cap V\neq\emptyset$ and thus $(U\times V)\cap(A\times B)\neq\emptyset$ which finally leads to $W\cap(A\times B)\neq\emptyset$. $\Box$